# System.Location class in Apex - why is it described in docs and why I can't use it in code?

Tags: apex, soap-api, geolocation

At first I've found out that I can't refer SObject field with type Geolocation directly, I get

> Data type not supported: Location

But I can access mySObject__Latitude__s and longitude.

I've tried to use [Location](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_class_system_Location.htm) class  in code and it's not compiled. I've tried to do that in many API versions of a class.

Is that class available in any API version? If not - why is it described in docs? And why when I call `describeSObject` and get fields of SObject, I get SoapType `location` which is not supported?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. I believe the class is part of Spring '15 update and your code is not using Spring '15 or your org does not yet have Spring '15.

[New Classes - Spring '15 Update](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000206831&language=en_US)